# Include with tags dynamic value in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, tags

I'm confused about how can I assign dynamic value to custom_variable using `include` `with` in Django based on the click button it is possible? I just want to show the modal based on the clicked button

```
{% include "modal_main.html" with custom_variable="dynamic_variable" %}


<button type="button" class="btn btn-label-primary button_orange">Orange</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-label-primary button_mango">Mango</button>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button_orange').click(function (event) {
       //pass data to custom_variable which is value of orange
    });

    $('.button_mango').click(function (event) {
       //pass data to custom_variable which is value of mango
    });

 });
```

Comment: That's never going to work. The template has already been rendered by the time the javascript is run, so there isn't even a variable to assign to. Why not just do whatever it is that you need to do with the data right there in the event callback functions?